# cakephp Paginator has lost the current page when return from a view

Tags: cakephp, paginator

I have the paginator working perfect with my view to generate a page view for items. However when you are on let's say page [8] and you visit on of the items and return to the list view the paginator start from page 1 instead of returning to the last page[8] 
I have searched high and low in how to get this fixed but no result, am I doing something wrong? Is there an easy fix/solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, this is the expected behaviour. Cake won't try to remember what page you were up to.

There is an easy solution - just store the last accessed page number in the session, and then you can get it again when needed.

The [Pagination Recall Component](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Zaphod/2012/03/27/paginationrecall_for_cakephp_2_x) should do what you want.

Comment: would you mind to give an example in how to use it with session?

Comment: How to use this Pagination recall component? I managed to get the latest version, uploaded it and put the component in my AppController with: var $components = array('PaginationRecall'); 
This is the first time I am going to use a component, would someone mind to explain this novice how to use it? Thanks

Comment: 1. Put it in your app/Controllers/components directory. 2) include the component in the controllers you need it (or, in AppController to implement it in all your controllers) - just need this line of codeL public $components = array('PaginationRecall');

Comment: More info on configuring components here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain.